# zabbix monitor for read only fs

Tags: linux, zabbix

Trying to monitor filesystems with zabbix. I found this : https://github.com/vintagegamingsystems/Zabbix-Read-Only-Filesystem-Check

and been trying to implement it. But I don't understand given this user parameter: `UserParameter=checkro[*],/etc/zabbix/scripts/checkro.sh $1`

What should be the item key. According to the documents `checkro` should work but I keep getting `Status Unsupported`. Tried posting this on zabbix forms but it takes 3-5 days for them to approve my post :/

EDIT : Files changed : `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` I added a line for the UserParameter and added the checkro.sh script. I restarted zabbix after was (it's a container, so technically restarted the container)

What I was expecting was for `checkro[something]` to be supported as item key but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`[*]` indicates that this item key takes parameters. The script has this line: `mountPoint=$1`.

Thus the item key should have the mountpoint passed as a parameter like so:

```
checkro[/home]
```

Comment: I have tired that but it still says "Unsupported item key"

Comment: Provide all the detail on what exactly have you done so far. Which files have been edited for what changes, what commands have been run etc.

Comment: added some details to the post.

Comment: Please be more specific - what exact line did you add, what exact key did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late. But I just used this script. It works only if / and /boot. If your FS is on say /dev/MAPPER etc it does not work.